# Scrollview and Flatlast causing error in my react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, scrollview, flatlist

so im currently learning react-native and i have been having this error since yesterday while using flatlist and scrollview. it worked initially but suddenly the error started.

requireNativeComponent: "RCTScrollContentView" was not found in the UIManager

[image]

please note that im using expo and react-native

heres my code.

App.jsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import CatScreen from './screens/CatScreen';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <CatScreen/>
      <StatusBar style='auto'/>
    </>

  );
}
```

screens/Catscreen

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native'
import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data'
import CategoryGrid from '../components/Griditems'

const CatScreen = () => {
  return (
    <FlatList
        data={CATEGORIES} 
        key={2}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={item=>item.id}
        renderItem={({item})=>(
            <CategoryGrid title={item.title} color={item.color}/>
        )}
    />
  )
}

export default CatScreen
```

components/Griditems

```
import { Pressable, View, Text, StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native"


const CategoryGrid = ({title, color}) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.gridItem, {backgroundColor:color}]}>
        <Pressable 
            //andriod ripple works only for andriod, so the presses function is needed to simulate an effect for ios
            android_ripple={{color:'#ccc'}} 
            style={(press)=>[ styles.pressableContainer, press.pressed ? styles.pressableContainerPress : null]}
        >
            <View style={styles.innerContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
            </View>
        </Pressable>
    </View>
  )
}

export default CategoryGrid

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    gridItem:{
        flex:1,
        margin:10,
        height:150,
        borderRadius:8,
        //for andriod
        elevation: 3,
        overflow:Platform.OS = 'android'? 'hidden' : 'visible',
        //for ios
        backgroundColor:'white',
        shadowColor:'black',
        shadowOpacity:0.25,
        shadowOffset:{width:0, height:2},
        shadowRadius:8
    },
    pressableContainer:{
        flex:1,
    },
    pressableContainerPress:{
        opacity:0.5,
    },
    innerContainer:{
        flex:1,
        padding:16,
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    title:{
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontSize:18
    }
})
```

i have updated both expo and react native to the latest version but still having the issue. i even started the project again, it work but any i stop my server and start again i get the error